# OpenSSL compatible API for Scala?

Tags: scala, openssl, lift

I'm working on a project with a friend. He's implementing his software in Ruby and I'm doing my stuff in Scala (with Lift). We're using some asynchronous encryption and he is using the ruby OpenSSL bindings for that:

```
 key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(4096)
 self.public_key = key.public_key
 self.private_key = key
```

What I'm looking for is a simple API which is compatible to OpenSSL and runs on the JVM. I need it to create key-pairs and to encrypt and sign our payload. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

How about using the API available in the JDK? `javax.crypto.*`

A college has been using it for SSL related stuff (using a cert and RSA keys).

Have a look at [the Java API docs.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#HowSSLWorks)

Comment: I looked at the API and managed to create a keypair. I didn't find any methods to take an openSSL key (DER-format) as a string and create a keypair from it or take my Java/Scala generated keypair and create a string in DER-format from it.

Answer (score 0):

PEM is just `header` + `base64(`PKCS#8 encoded key material`)` + `footer`; the standard JCE stuff uses PKCS#8 format natively.  It's not exactly simple, but it works. :)